# How to replace variables with names using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider a column(Result) in a data frame df which is stored with 0's and 1's.

0 indicates Fail and 1 indicates Pass.

How do I replace 0's with Fail and 1's with Pass for df['Result'] column?

Comment: `df['Result']=df['Result'].map({0:'Fail',1:'Pass'})`

Comment: Or `df["Result"] = np.where(df["Result"]==1,"Pass","Fail")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us [`pandas.Series.map`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+map&oq=pandas+map&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i65l3.1855j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
df.results = df.results.map({0: 'Fail', 1: 'Pass'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Result'] == 0, 'Fail', 'Pass')
```